# Configure site to support the URL reference with and without the "www"

Tags: alternate-access-mapping, host-named

I have created multiple HNSC under a unique Web Application as follows: 
http://site1.com, http://site2.com, http://site3.com.

I would like to be able to access any of these site collections using both http://site1.com and http://www.site1.com.

Currently, I am able to access the site using http://site1.com but when I try using www I get the following error: Alternate access mappings have not been configured.  Users or services are accessing the site http://site1.com with the URL http://www.site1.com.

Do I really need to use an AAM? I was under the impression that this was not necessary if using HNSC. Or do I need to create the HNSC using www?

Comment: did you see any entry in AAM for your urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one URL per zone is allowed for the HNSC collections. this is by design. Now you have two options.

- Remove the exiting default url and add the new url in default zone
- Or add the new url into different zone so both URL will be accessible for the users.

[Unable to add URLs using Set-SPSiteUrl in SharePoint 2013 RTM](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2826457?wa=wsignin1.0)

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. There are no entries in AAM for the url's. If I create a new default zone through Central Admin with the url (ie http:// www . site2.com), how do I map this to the right HNSC (http://site2.com)?

Comment: No, you need to add that url in different zone of hnsc....using set-up siteurl....

Comment: Thanks. I'll try though PowerShell then and will let you know the outcome

Comment: That worked, thanks! This is not achievable through Central Admin then?

Comment: Nope...hnsc only via powershell

Comment: So, if I need to list or remove any of these newly created zones? Is that through PS too?

Comment: That is correct.